# Equivalence of Graphical model selection algorithms

Tags: pr.probability, estimation-theory

Suppose, a jointly Gaussian random vector is denoted by $X \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$ and $X$ has a distribution given by $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)$. It is known that estimating the graphical model that defines this random vector is equivalent to estimating the sparsity pattern of the inverse covariance matrix, i.e. $\Sigma ^{-1}$. Suppose the sparsity pattern is in the form of a tree. It is well known that [Chou Liu's](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/csc2515-2006/readings/chowliu.pdf) algorithm can be applied to recover that graphical model structure in this case. How can be prove that this algorithm will recover the sparsity pattern of the $\Sigma^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Please do not simultaneously cross-post at multiple SE sites, as you did here http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31208 . It fragments the discussion and leads to duplication of effort.

Comment: Thanks for notifying me. I will remove the question here.

Comment: I changed my mind and thought it is more suitable for this forum. I have deleted the version of this question on theory cs stack exchange.